# Is nested synchronized block necessary?

Tags: java, synchronization, nested

I am writing a multithreaded program and I have a method that has a nested synchronized blocks and I was wondering if I need the inner sync or if just the outer sync is good enough.

```
public class Tester {

    private BlockingQueue<Ticket> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void acceptTicket(Ticket p) {
        try {
            synchronized (q) {
                q.put(p);

                synchronized (list) {
                    if (list.size() < 5) {
                        list.add(p.getSize());
                    } else {
                        list.remove(0);
                        list.add(p.getSize());
                        }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT:
This isn't a complete class as I am still working on it. But essentially I am trying to emulate a ticket machine. The ticket machine maintains a list of tickets in the `BlockingQueue` q. Whenever a client adds a ticket to the machine, the machine also keeps track of the price of the last 5 tickets (`ArrayList` list). So I don't believe I need the inner sync because its is only this class (the ticket system) that will access the `list`

Comment: @Dan, if you give the rest of the class code it will help people to understand exactly what is happening, and give you a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The danger with:

```
    synchronized (q) {
        synchronized (list) {
         }
    }
```

Is one day you'll add a method, or call methods in such an order that in effect it does this as well:

```
    synchronized (list) {
        synchronized (q) {
         }
    }
```

Then it's just a deadlock timebomb.

Asuming this is the complete class, you can just lock one, or as is common, lock the object itself with `synchronized` on the method. All other access to these privates will need to be synchronized too.

```
public class Tester {

private BlockingQueue<Ticket> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

public synchronized void acceptTicket(Ticket p) {
    try {
      q.put(p);

      if (list.size() < 5) {
        list.add(p.getSize());
      } else {
        list.remove(0);
        list.add(p.getSize());
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    
}
```

Or cleaner:

```
public class Tester {

private BlockingQueue<Ticket> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void acceptTicket(Ticket p) {
    try {
      //this is cleaner, because I don't know what logger class is doing,
      //I want to eliminate chance of deadlock and reduce time we are in lock
      synchronized (this){
        q.put(p);

        if (list.size() < 5) {
          list.add(p.getSize());
        } else {
          list.remove(0);
          list.add(p.getSize());
        }
     }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    
}
```

Cleaner still, but is unlikely to be nessasary in your case (based on what I have seen):

```
public class Tester {

private final Object lockObj = new Object(); //specific object for locking
                                //could use any other private, non-exposed final but
                                //this makes it absolutely clear what I should be
                                //using for locks
private BlockingQueue<Ticket> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void acceptTicket(Ticket p) {
    try {
      //"this" can be locked by external code outside my control here,
      //so I use a specific private final object lockObj to eliminate deadlocks and
      //provide finer grained locking - reducing contension
      synchronized (lockObj){
        q.put(p);

        if (list.size() < 5) {
          list.add(p.getSize());
        } else {
          list.remove(0);
          list.add(p.getSize());
        }
     }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the intent of the above code is to group all the operations (the store in the queue, and the store in the list) in an atomic operation. So yes, the outer synchronized block is all you need. Holding multiple locks at once is a good way to end up with deadlocks, so it should be avoided when possible.

I wouldn't use the queue itself as the lock, though, but a dedicated final lock object instead.

And most importantly: the above code alone doesn't make any sense, since the list and the queue aren't used anywhere else. So what I just said could be true, or completely false depending on what the rest of the actual code does.

Comment: Can you explain why you wouldn't use the queue as the lock? I get this warning from netbeans that i'm syncing on a non-final field. Would it make the lock useless?

Comment: Because the queue's responsibility is not to guard operations on itself and other objects. Give each object only one responsibility. Moreover, using a non-final field as a lock is dangerous because you might assign a new object to the field, and thus have two methods synchronized on two different objects although the both use the same field as the lock.